# How to trigger an event once an external Javascript is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

Trying to trigger a click event and scroll to top but it is an external javascript.
See Embedded script below

```
(function() {
  (window.$fs || (window.$fs = [])).push([ "embed", {"root":"fs-embed-vvw2IIvtaz","host":"bikeridersnyc.fullslate.com"} ]);
  if (!window.$fs._isFullSlate) { 
    var fsscr = document.createElement("script"); 
        fsscr.type = "text/javascript";fsscr.async = true; 
        fsscr.src = ["http", (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "s" : ""), "://bikeridersnyc.fullslate.com/api.js"].join("");
    var other = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; 
        other.parentNode.insertBefore(fsscr, other); 
  }
})();
```

It is embedded from [HERE](https://bikeridersnyc.fullslate.com/).
And live on [this staging site](http://dev.bikeridersnyc.com/appointments/)

Now I am trying to once you click a link on the page of this specific embedded element, it scrolls the window to the top.
Something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.fs-booking-choices a').click(function() {
     $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
     return false;
  });
});
```

It should work but some reason it doesn't... Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: why not just import the usual way? Could you create a fiddle please? I don't find it on your page and maybe I would need to test some things ;)

Comment: I took another route, but thanks for offering your help!